# hadoop configuration with ODI 12c

Tags: oracle, hadoop, integration, etl, oracle-data-integrator

I have installed hadoop 2.7 in my windows. The hadoop is working fine and all the 4 services are running. I want to integrate hadoop with my ETL tool ODI 12c. To integrate it, I need following details -

1. HDFS Namenode URI
2. Resource manager/ job tracker URI
3. ODI HDFS root

What should I input there?
By default it is set as - hdfs://localhost:8020,localhost:8032 and /user/anmojain/odi_home simeltaneously. When I am trying to connect it is showing error. Please find the screenshot for reference. Thanks in advance.

The image consists of the ODI snapshot

Comment: Where is your screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

You should put in your fields:

**1. HDFS Namenode URI**

```
URI of the HDFS cluster
```

**2. Resource manager/ job tracker**

```
URI of the resource manager or the job tracker. Ex. localhost:8032
```

**3. URI ODI HDFS root**

```
Path of the ODI HDFS root directory.Ex. /user/<login_username>/odi_home.
```

Source: https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/odi/odi-big-data/setup.htm#ODIBD122

Comment: .Thanks for your answer. I already tried that but the connection is unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0):

For HDFS Namenode URI, remember you should have configured

> core-site.xml

and added similar to following configuration, hdfs://localhost:9000 is the value you can give a try considering following configuration. You need to change as per your configuration.

```
<configuration>
<property>
  <name>fs.default.name</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

For ODI HDFS Root, remember you might have configured hdfs-site.xml setup namenode and datanode from the file system. After that you might have added folder location, I used following commands in my case and used

> /hdfs_u01/hadoop/odi

as ODI HDFS Root, give a try if it works.

```
hdfs dfs -mkdir /hdfs_u01
hdfs dfs -mkdir /hdfs_u01/hadoop
hdfs dfs -mkdir /hdfs_u01/hadoop/odi
```

Comment: For Resource manager/ job tracker, it should be localhost:8032 @jedijs but in my case localhost:8042 however I have not modified it. Give a try for localhost:8042 if localhost:8032 didn't work.